# How do I wake up a MacBook with it's lid still closed?

Tags: mac, wake-up

I want to wake my sleeping macbook up with lid close. I tried the "schedule" option in energy saving but failed. Is there any way to let macbook wake up itself while the lid is kept close? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can most probably wake it up through [WoL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) from another machine.  Try [this software](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/wakeonlan.html) if you have another Mac.  You can also send WoL magic packets from Tomato and DD-WRT routers, if you have one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in *any* USB device. I frequently use a flash drive to wake mine up.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in an external keyboard or mouse and hit the space bar/mouse button. It may require that an external display be plugged in. I've never tried it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a wireless USB, mouse, click it once.